# UIViewController question for iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I have an App with one MainWindow.xib file.  Then I have ViewControllerA.xib and ViewControllerB.xib.  My MainWindow.xib have one ViewController that points two ViewControllerA.xib.

On ViewControllerA I have a button and I would like the button, when pressed, to move ViewControllerB onto the screen.  How do I do that?

I tried this code, but I think I am missing something:

```
- (IBAction)btMyButton:(id)sender
{
    ViewControllerB * viewController = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

My ViewControllerB does appear, but it is squashed at the top of the screen, over the previous view.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: if you aren't using a navigation controller project, your self.navigationController is probably not added to the window, and it is also probably nil.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I do not have a NavigationController.  Should I?  I thought if I put a NavigationController that I would have the bar across the top.   I do not want the bar across the top for the first screen, but when the user clicks the button, I will go to a navigation controller view.

Comment: you don't need to have a bar if you don't want to, you can use [self presentModalViewController: animated:] if you just want to push a view controller, then call dissmissModelViewController:animated: on the view that called present... this can be done through self.parentViewController.

Comment: The navigation controller should have an outlet on the application delegate you can hide it on your first screen if you want.

Comment: but you should probably start a fresh navigation project and look at how the navigation controller is added, then use it, even if you hide the navigation bar.

Comment: Grady, as per your suggestion, I added the UINavigationController, seems to make more sense.  But, the reason I went away from this was I did not think you could hide the bar across the top.  So, any pointers on how to hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the view of controller B has correct hight you should subtract the navigation bar height 44 px and status bar 20 px as well. Those values are for iPhone.

```
  - (IBAction)btMyButton:(id)sender
    {
        //you should load from the main app bundle
        ViewControllerB * viewController = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        // you don't need the following line      
        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:viewController.view];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        [viewController release];
    }
```

**Update**
As the above comment says if you may don't have a navigation controller to push Controller B into. So Add a navigation controller into the main window instead of the view controller and make its root view controller you Controller A.

I hope this helps you,

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:viewController.view];
```

You are adding the view twice. The 2nd and 3rd lines both cause the view to be added to the view hierarchy in different places.

--update--
If you remove the 2nd line and are not seeing your view then self.navigationController is most likely nil. Try [self presentModalViewController:] instead.

Comment: Yes, I did remove it and then nothing happens and I do not see the ViewControllerB at all.  Also, to note, I have this button in my ViewControllerA class.  So I was questioning the self?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to remove old viewcontroller from main windows.

```
- (IBAction)btMyButton:(id)sender
{

//Assuming you declare two Iboutlet controllerA, controllerB mapping with that view as class variable
{
if (self.controllerB == nil)
{
    ViewControllerB * viewController = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
    self.controllerB = viewController;
[viewController release];
}
[controllerA.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view insertSubview:controllerB.view atIndex:0];
}

}
```